# Reading data from csv file C++

Tags: c++, csv, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

Hi my project have many csv files. Which is located in the same directory as `Datafolder/IAG/day1.csv, Datafolder/IAG/day2.csv and Datafolder/IAG/day3.csv`. Same for `Datafolder/CBA/day1.csv, Datafolder/CBA/day2.csv and Datafolder/CBA/day3.csv` and `Datafolder/NAB/day1.csv, Datafolder/NAB/day2.csv and Datafolder/NAB/day3.csv`.
my goal is user can input which day's data they want and input. Once they input it will ask the user to enter either 1(to get the highest price value) or 2(lowest price value). But in my code I dont why once the user select the day and get the highest price it is stored as that value. Even though the user select another day and look for the highest price it is not actually displaying that day's highest value but the previous day's highest value which copied over again The following is codes. Thanks in advance guys.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "vector.h"
#include "stock.h"
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int counter = 0;
    double highestPrice=0, lowestPrice=0;
    ofstream outfile;
    string sFileName;
    string record;
    Stock S1;
    Vector<Stock> data;
    int option;
    ifstream codeindex;
    ifstream IAGsales;
    ifstream CBAsales;
    ifstream NABsales;
    ifstream* Tempsales = 0;
    ifstream infile;
    map<string,Vector<Stock>> mapIAG;
    map<string,Vector<Stock>> mapCBA;
    map<string,Vector<Stock>> mapNAB;
    map<string,Vector<Stock>> mapTemp;
    map<string,Vector<Stock>>::iterator it;

    double price1, price2;
    Time time1, time2;
    Date date1;
    string sXCode,sInputDate;
int main()
{

    void initializing();
    codeindex.open("Datafolder/code_index.txt");
    if(! codeindex)
    {
        cout << codeindex <<" : File not found!!" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }


    do
    {
        initializing();
        time1.initialize();
        highestPrice = (data.getvalue(0)).getprice();//Initialise highest price
        lowestPrice=0;
        lowestPrice = (data.getvalue(0)).getprice();//Initialise lowest price
        (data.getvalue(0)).gettime(time1, data.getvalue(0));//Initialise time1

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                Date datehigh;
                for(int i = 1 ; i < counter ; i ++)
                {
                    if((data.getvalue(i)).getprice() > highestPrice)
                    {
                        highestPrice = (data.getvalue(i)).getprice();
                        (data.getvalue(i)).gettime(time1, data.getvalue(i));//get the time when highest price first occurred
                        (data.getvalue(i)).getdate(datehigh, data.getvalue(i));
                    }
                }   
                cout << "Date: " << datehigh << endl;
                cout << "Highest price : " << highestPrice << endl;
                cout << "Start time(s): " << endl;
                cout << time1 ;

                for(int i = 0 ; i < counter ; i ++)
                {
                    if( (data.getvalue(i)).getprice() == highestPrice)
                    {
                        (data.getvalue(i)).gettime(time2, data.getvalue(i));//get the time when highest price occurred

                        if(time2 != time1)//avoid duplicated time
                        {
                            (data.getvalue(i)).printtime();
                            (data.getvalue(i)).gettime(time1, data.getvalue(i));
                            //(data.getvalue(i)).getdate(datehigh, data.getvalue(i));
                        }
                    }//End of if( (data.get(i)).getprice() == highestPrice)
                }//End of for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i ++)
                //main();
            //initialize();
            //(data.getvalue(0)).printdate();


                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {   
            Date datelow;
                for(int i = 1 ; i < counter ; i ++)
                {

                    if(((data.getvalue(i)).getprice() < lowestPrice) && ((data.getvalue(i)).getprice() > 0))
                    {
                        lowestPrice = (data.getvalue(i)).getprice();
                        (data.getvalue(i)).gettime(time1, data.getvalue(i));//get the time when lowest price first occurred
                        (data.getvalue(i)).getdate(datelow, data.getvalue(i));
                    }

                } 
                int j =0;
                //(data.getvalue(j)).printdate();

                cout << "Date: " << datelow << endl;
                cout << "Lowest price: " << lowestPrice << endl;
                cout << "Start time(s): " << endl;
                cout << time1<<endl;

                for(int i = 0 ; i < counter ; i ++)
                {
                    if( (data.getvalue(i)).getprice() == lowestPrice)
                    {
                        (data.getvalue(i)).gettime(time2, data.getvalue(i));//get the time when highest price occurred

                        if(time2 != time1)//avoid duplicated time
                        {
                            (data.getvalue(i)).printtime();
                            (data.getvalue(i)).gettime(time1, data.getvalue(i));
                        }
                    }//End of if( (data.get(i)).getprice() == lowestPrice)
                }//End of for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i ++)
                //main();
            //initialize();
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                outfile.open("output.csv");
                if(! outfile)
                {
                    cout << "Can not open outfile" << endl;
                    exit(1);
                }
                cout << "Data processing" << endl;
                outfile << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
                outfile << "Date,Start time,Price of share,Volume of shares traded,Total value of shares traded" << endl;
                price1 = data.getvalue(counter-1).getprice();//get price for the last row
                double nVolumeOfTrades = data.getvalue(counter-1).getvolume();
                double ntotalValueOfShares = data.getvalue(counter-1).getvalue();
                // Get Date of trading
                data.getvalue(counter-1).getdate(date1,data.getvalue(counter-1));
                // Get Start time
                data.getvalue(counter-1).gettime(time1,data.getvalue(counter-1));

                for(int i = counter-2; i > -1 ; i --)
                {
                    price2 = data.getvalue(i).getprice();
                    if(price2 != 0 && price1 != price2)
                    {
                        // Write values to file.
                        outfile << date1 << "," << time1 << "," << price1 << "," << nVolumeOfTrades << "," << ntotalValueOfShares << endl;

                        // Get Date of trading
                        data.getvalue(i).getdate(date1,data.getvalue(i));
                        // Get Start time
                        data.getvalue(i).gettime(time1,data.getvalue(i));

                        price1 = data.getvalue(i).getprice();
                        nVolumeOfTrades = 0;
                        ntotalValueOfShares = 0;
                    }
                    nVolumeOfTrades += data.getvalue(i).getvolume();
                    ntotalValueOfShares += data.getvalue(i).getvalue();
                }
                cout << "Data processed" << endl;
                outfile.close();
                //initialize();

                //main();
                break;
            }
        case 4:
            {
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                cout << "Invalid option" << endl;
                cout<<"Choose from options 1 to 4: "<<endl;
                cout << "Enter 1 to get the highest stock price & time:" << endl;
                cout << "Enter 2 to get the lowest stock price & time:" << endl;
                cout << "Enter 3 to output the csv file: " << endl;
                cout << "Enter 4 to exit from the program:" << endl;
                cin >> option;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(option==4)
        {
            break;
        }

        cout << "\n\n" << endl;
    }


    while(1);

    return 0;
}

void initializing()
{
  // Present the user with Input options
        cout<<"Enter the code of transaction:" <<endl;
        while(! codeindex.eof()){

            getline(codeindex,record);
            cout<<record<<endl;
        }
        cin>>sXCode;
        codeindex.clear();
        codeindex.seekg(0,ios::beg);
        while(sXCode!="IAG" && sXCode!="CBA" && sXCode!="NAB"){
            cout<<"Wrong input .. Please enter again \n";
            cin>>sXCode;

        }

        // Get code file name.
        if(sXCode=="IAG")
        {
            if(IAGsales.is_open()==true){

            IAGsales.close();
            }
            IAGsales.open("Datafolder/IAG/sales_index.txt");

            if(!IAGsales)
            {
                cout << IAGsales<<" :File not found!!" << endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                exit(1);
            }

            // Read IAG file names.
            while(!IAGsales.eof())
            {
                getline(IAGsales, sFileName);
                if(sFileName.size() > 0)
                { //cout<<"before: "<< sFilePath <<endl;
                    string sFilePath = "Datafolder/IAG/";
                    sFilePath = sFilePath.append(sFileName);
                    cout<<"after append: "<< sFilePath <<endl;
                    // Read the csv file
                    infile.open(sFilePath);
                    if(! infile)
                    {
                        cout << sFileName<<": File not found!!" << endl;
                        exit(1);
                    }

                    getline(infile, record);//first line
                    getline(infile, record);//second line

                    while(! infile.eof())
                    {
                        getline(infile, record);
                        if(record.size() > 0)
                        {
                            S1.readfile(record, S1);
                            data.insert(S1);
                            counter ++;
                        }
                    }//while(! infile.eof())
                    infile.close();

                    // Insert to Map
                    mapIAG.insert(pair<string,Vector<Stock>>(sFileName,data));
                }

            }






            IAGsales.clear();
            IAGsales.seekg(0,ios::beg);
            Tempsales = &IAGsales;
            //cout<<"test1";
            //IAGsales.close();
        }
        else if(sXCode=="CBA")
        {

            if(CBAsales.is_open()==true){

            CBAsales.close();
            }

            CBAsales.open("Datafolder/CBA/sales_index.txt");
            if(!CBAsales)
            {
                cout << CBAsales<<" : File not found!!" << endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                exit(1);
            }

            // Read IAG file names.
            while(!CBAsales.eof())
            {
                getline(CBAsales, sFileName);
                if(sFileName.size() > 0)
                {
                    string sFilePath = "Datafolder/CBA/";
                    sFilePath = sFilePath.append(sFileName);
                    // Read the csv file
                    infile.open(sFilePath);
                    if(! infile)
                    {
                        cout << sFileName<<": File not foud!!!" << endl;
                        exit(1);
                    }

                    getline(infile, record);//first line
                    getline(infile, record);//second line

                    while(! infile.eof())
                    {
                        getline(infile, record);
                        if(record.size() > 0)
                        {
                            S1.readfile(record, S1);
                            data.insert(S1);
                            counter ++;
                        }
                    }//while(! infile.eof())
                    infile.close();

                    // Insert to Map
                    mapIAG.insert(pair<string,Vector<Stock>>(sFileName,data));
                }
            }






            CBAsales.clear();
            CBAsales.seekg(0,ios::beg);
            Tempsales = &CBAsales;
            //cout<<"test2";
        }
        else 
        {

            if(NABsales.is_open()==true){

            NABsales.close();
            }

            NABsales.open("Datafolder/NAB/sales_index.txt");
            if(!NABsales)
            {
                cout << NABsales<<" : File not found!!!!" << endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                exit(1);
            }

            // Read IAG file names.
            while(!NABsales.eof())
            {
                getline(NABsales, sFileName);
                if(sFileName.size() > 0)
                {
                    string sFilePath = "Datafolder/NAB/";
                    sFilePath = sFilePath.append(sFileName);
                    // Read the csv file
                    infile.open(sFilePath);
                    if(! infile)
                    {
                        cout << sFileName<<": File not foud!!" << endl;
                        exit(1);
                    }

                    getline(infile, record);//first line
                    getline(infile, record);//second line

                    while(! infile.eof())
                    {
                        getline(infile, record);
                        if(record.size() > 0)
                        {
                            S1.readfile(record, S1);
                            data.insert(S1);
                            counter ++;
                        }
                    }//while(! infile.eof())
                    infile.close();

                    // Insert to Map
                    mapIAG.insert(pair<string,Vector<Stock>>(sFileName,data));
                }
            }   
            NABsales.clear();
            NABsales.seekg(0,ios::beg);
            Tempsales = &NABsales;
            //cout<<"test3";

        }


         highestPrice = (data.getvalue(0)).getprice();//Initialise highest price
    lowestPrice = (data.getvalue(0)).getprice();//Initialise lowest price
    (data.getvalue(0)).gettime(time1, data.getvalue(0));//Initialise time1


        cout<<"Enter the date of transaction:" <<endl;
        while(!Tempsales->eof()){
            getline(*Tempsales,record);
            cout<<record<<endl;
        }
        cin>>sInputDate;

        cout<<"Choose from options 1 to 4: "<<endl;
        cout << "Enter 1 to get the highest stock price & time:" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 2 to get the lowest stock price & time:" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 3 to output the csv file: " << endl;
        cout << "Enter 4 to exit from the program:" << endl;
        cin >> option;

        // Get the vector from Map based on Date.
        if(sXCode=="IAG")
        {
            it = mapIAG.find(sInputDate);
            data = it->second;
        }
        else if(sXCode=="CBA")
        {
            it = mapIAG.find(sInputDate);
            data = it->second;
        }
        else
        {
            it = mapIAG.find(sInputDate);
            data = it->second;
        }


}
```

Stock is a Vector.

Comment: [`while(! infile.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) isn't such a good idea most of the time.

Comment: Oh ok.. But Mr.Pei what possibly went wrong here? Any idea?

Comment: It's well described in the linked Q&A what may go wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have your own implementation of vector?

Comment: Yes Ashkan. That's right

Comment: That's a lot of code to wade through. And you don't provide ALL the necessary code either, so it's imppossible to say, for example, whether your vector class is wrong in some way.